# Python code with threading works but not with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Python code that makes very basic usage of the threading package: `Thread()`, `start()` and `join()`. This works fine. Also the non-threaded version of the code works fine (serially ofcourse). However when working with `multiprocessing`, i.e. replacing the `Thread()` with `Process()` and keeping the `start()` and `join()` as is I get type errors on parts of the code that have not been parallelized at all. Any idea why using multiprocessing can cause such side-effects? Where and how should I look for issues in my code?

Comment: Can you please post your code for reference.

Comment: And please post the exact error stack traces, too. Multiprocessing needs to serialize (e.g. pickle) your data across multiple processes, hence you can get all kinds of errors from and after that.

Comment: Further to @PseudoAj: You may also want to read [mcve].